# How to bind Repeater control to separate List<String> values

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using asp.net webforms c# project and I have a repeater control as below.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" id="rptNames" onItemDataBound="rptName_ItemDataBound" >
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table border="1" style="border-color:Red;">
                <tr>
                    <td>First Title</td>
                    <td>Second Title</td>
                </tr>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>

            </tr>     
        </ItemTemplate>       
        <FooterTemplate>
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I want to bind this repeater control to a method that returns `List<string>` as below.

Title1
Title2 
Title3
Title4

And I have another method that returns different `List<string>` as below. It should be bind to the second column in the repeater control.

Title1
Title2

The final result should look something like below.

[image]

Comment: Pretty sure a repeater can only return items from a single dataset.  I don't think you can do this the way you want to.

Comment: Can I combine the results from both the methods to a single dataset. If yes how can I achieve this?

Comment: Same way you'd do it in any query.  Join the two on a key field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your code design. 
Create a Class and than create a list collection of that class.

Here is an example.

```
public class TitleClass
{
  public string Title1 {get;set;}
  public string Title2 {get;set;}
}

public void BindListToRepeater()
{
List<TitleClass> titleList = new[]{ new TitleClass{ Title1 = "title1", Title2="title2" }};
        rptNames.DataSource = titleList;
        rptNames.DataBind();
}
```

Now Create your List of the above class and bind your list to the Repeater control.

Comment: If title and value are related, please create datatable or array list and fill data and bind it.